# program says it isn't a valid input when it is

Tags: python

I've run into a bug where the program seems to think that my input into an input statement isn't within the parameters, when it clearly is.

This is the code i'm having trouble with:

```
time.sleep(1.5)
print()
print()
print("You have chosen", horsechoice)
time.sleep(1)
print("How much do you want to bet?")
while True:
    try:
        moneyinput = int(input())
        racebegin(moneyinput)
        break
    except:
        print("Not a valid amount of money.")
        continue
```

Even when I input an integer, it still states that I didn't input a valid amount of money.

Comment: You should include `racebegin()` - the exception might be there.

Comment: When you use a bare `try:except:`, anything could be wrong inside. When any exception is triggered, it just prints out the message. It could be inside `racebegin()`. What is that function? Could it raise an exception? Perhaps you could try the line: `racebegin(moneyinput)` just below the `try:except:` to see.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to check the input validity, you should wrap the `try/except` only around the `int(input())` call, not `racebegin()`. Your code is probably catching an error in `racebegin()`.

It's also a good idea to narrow down the type of error you're catching with `except:`. Doing that might have prevented the problem in the original code, unless `racebegin()` was also raising `ValueError`.

```
while True:
    try:
        moneyinput = int(input())
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid amount of money.")

racebegin(moneyinput)
```

Comment: If we're showcasing best practices, should probably scope the `except:` to only catch the specific exception type expected (`except ValueError:`?). Even better would be to continue to summarize the content (`except ValueError as e: print("Not a valid amount of money: %s" % e)`?)

Comment: I've added the exception type. But the error message for ValueError is not really user-friendly, so I'll leave that out.